# integration testing of Jooby application using Spock

Tags: rest, kotlin, spock, jooby

I've got pretty simple application that uses `Jooby` as web framework. Its class responsible for REST looks like this

```
class Sandbox : Kooby ({
    path("/sandbox") {
        get {
            val environment = require(Config::class).getString("application.env")
            "Current environment: $environment"
        }

        get ("/:name") {
            val name = param("name")
            "Auto response $name"
        }
    }
})
```

I want to write integration test for it. My test looks like this. I use `spock` and `rest-assured`. The thing is that I don't have the application running and want to run it using some kind of embedded server or whatever.  How to do that?

My simple test looks like this

```
class SandboxTest extends Specification {

    def "check current environment"() {
        given:
            def request = given()
        when:
            def response = request.when().get("/sandbox")
        then:
            response.then().statusCode(200) // for now 404
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for before/after test (or class) hooks in Spock. In the before hook you start Jooby without blocking the thread:

```
app.start("server.join=false")
```

in the after hook:

```
app.stop();
```

Never used Spock but here is a small extension method for **Spek**:

```
fun SpecBody.jooby(app: Jooby, body: SpecBody.() -> Unit) {
  beforeGroup {
    app.start("server.join=false")
  }

  body()

  afterGroup {
    app.stop()
  }
}
```

Finally from your test:

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class)
object AppTest : Spek({
  jooby(App()) {
    describe("Get with query parameter") {
        given("queryParameter name=Kotlin") {
            it("should return Hello Kotlin!") {
                val name = "Kotlin"
                given()
                        .queryParam("name", name)
                        .`when`()
                        .get("/")
                        .then()
                        .assertThat()
                        .statusCode(Status.OK.value())
                        .extract()
                        .asString()
                        .let {
                            assertEquals(it, "Hello $name!")
                        }
            }
         ...
      ...
   ...
...
```

[Maven Spek example](https://github.com/jooby-project/kotlin-starter/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/starter/kotlin/AppTest.kt)

[Gradle Spek example](https://github.com/jooby-project/kotlin-gradle-starter/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/starter/kotlin/AppTest.kt)